# Javascript: parameter set to null even though value is given

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem regarding my smooth scroll function, when I try to call it in my HTML with a parameter, the parameter "doesn't register" and my parameter variable gets null.

```
function yPosition() {
    if (self.pageYOffset) return self.pageYOffset;
    if (document.body.scrollTop) return document.body.scrollTop;
    return 0;
}

function elementYPosition(eID) {
    var element = document.getElementById(eID);
    var y = element.offsetTop;
    var node = element;
    while (node.offsetParent && node.offsetParent != document.body) {
        node = node.offsetParent;
        y += node.offsetTop;
    } return y;
}

function scroll(eID) {
    var startY = yPosition();
    var stopY = elementYPosition (eID);
    var distance = stopY > startY ? stopY - startY : startY - stopY;
    if (distance < 100) {
        scrollTo(0, stopY);
        return;
    }
    var speed = Math.round( distance / 100 );
    if (speed >= 20) speed = 20;
    var step = Math.round( distance / 25 );
    var leapY = stopY > startY ? startY + step : startY - step;
    var timer = 0;
    if (stopY > startY) {
        for ( var i = startY; i < stopY; i += step) {
            setTimeout("window.scrollTo(0, "+leapY+")", timer * speed);
            leapY -= step;
            if (leapY > stopY) {
                leapY = stopY;
                timer++;
            }
        }
        return;
    }
    for ( var i = startY; i > stopY; i-= step ) {
        setTimeout("window.scrollTo(0, "+leapY+")", timer * speed);
        leapY -= step;
        if ( leapY < stopY) {
            leapY = stopY;
            timer++;
        }
    }
}
```

relevant html:

```
<div id="scroll">
            <a href="#problemScroll" onclick="scroll('abc'); return false"><img src="graphics/down_arrow.png" alt="down arrow" /></a>
</div>
```

console when ran:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetTop' of
null elementYPosition js.js:12

@ js.js:12scroll 
@ js.js:22onclick 
@ index.html:17
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line of code:

```
var element = document.getElementById(eID);
```

is apparently returning `null` such that when you then try to do:

```
var y = element.offsetTop;
```

You are trying to read the `.offsetTop` property on `null` which throws an exception.

That can happen for two main reasons:

1. If there is no element in your document with the id that matches what is in the `eID` argument
2. If you are calling it before that part of the page has finished loading and thus the element with that ID doesn't exist yet.

---

It appears that you are calling `scroll()` directly from your HTML with this:

```
onclick="scroll('abc'); return false"
```

So, it must be the `'abc'` ID value that is missing from your document.

---

FYI, you can verify this is the case by inserting a `console.log()` into your code like this:

```
function elementYPosition(eID) {
    var element = document.getElementById(eID);

    // insert this to check the element variable
    console.log(element);

    var y = element.offsetTop;
    var node = element;
    while (node.offsetParent && node.offsetParent != document.body) {
        node = node.offsetParent;
        y += node.offsetTop;
    } return y;
}
```

---

Presumably the fix for this is to make sure the element with the `'abc'` ID value exists in your document.

Comment: I had an anchor with abc as name that stood from the original jump-scroll that was in place, I totally neglected the fact that it of course had to be ID. The function is now errorless, but does not work as intended. I will post a new post describing the problem that has occurred as it is quite different from this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because there is no element with `id` "abc": this would be the reason for `nullelement`. Make sure you have one (there isn't one in the code you provided).

Other than that, the code should be valid.

Comment: I had an anchor with abc as name that stood from the original jump-scroll that was in place, I totally neglected the fact that it of course had to be ID. The function is now errorless, but does not work as intended. I will post a new post describing the problem that has occurred as it is quite different from this. Thank you.